# T-SQL: check if variable is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if variable `@varChar` is `NULL` **and** variable `@bit` is `0`.

My attempt:

```
if ISNULL(@varChar, false) and (@bit = 0) 
begin
    RAISERROR ('varchar was not specified', 16,1);
end
```

My problem is that `ISNULL(check_if_null, replacement_value)` does not work like this, and I can not find an alternative.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `IS NULL`:

```
IF @varCHAR IS NULL AND @bit = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('varchar was not specified', 16,1);
END
```

Another approach is:

```
DECLARE @varCHAR VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;

IF ISNULL(@varCHAR,'false') = 'false' AND @bit = 0
    RAISERROR ('varchar was not specified', 16,1);
```

Comment: The first solution checks for NULL. The second checks for a _magic value_ that may or may not occur in the data (`'false'`). Best practice is to avoid magic values.

Comment: @HABO I agree that we should avoid "magic" values at all cost and first approach is preferred. I just wanted to show OP that using  `ISNULL(@varChar, false)` is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IS NULL` when checking if a value is null.

```
IF @varChar IS NULL and @bit = 0 
    RAISERROR ('varchar was not specified', 16,1);
```